# For Each Loop Modification with Primitives

Tags: java, for-loop

```
int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
for (int i : arr){
    i = 1;
}
```

(Question 1): Why does this code segment not produce an error since it is using a for-each loop to modify elements?

```
 int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
  for (int i : arr){
      arr[i] = 1; 
  }
```

(Question 2): How does this code work even though the for each-loop is not being used properly. Nonetheless, somehow all the elements are set to 1?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think OP wants to know about exception due to concurrent modification. 1st case is not modifying the array but the second case is modying the array...

Comment: Adding link from another post for the above comment of mine...https://stackoverflow.com/a/24219216/504133

Answer (score 4):

> (Question 1): Why does this code segment not produce an error since it is using a for-each loop to modify elements?

It doesn't modify **elements**. What it does is modify **the variable `i`**, which at any point in time happens to contain a **copy of one of the elements**, but is otherwise completely unrelated to the array.

> (Question 2): How does this code work even though the for each-loop is not being used properly.

The loop may indeed look peculiar, but there's nothing fundamentally wrong with it. It is equivalent to the following code:

```
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 1;
arr[2] = 1;
arr[3] = 1;
arr[4] = 1;
arr[5] = 1;
```

Of course this only works because `arr` happens to contain valid indices into itself. If it didn't (for example, if `arr[0]=6`), you'd get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Hmm.. how about in second case there is no exception for concurrent modification

Comment: @nits.kk: Why would there be? Leaving aside the fact that `ConcurrentModificationException` is a best-effort thing, I don't think anything here is violating any contracts, no?

Answer (score 4):

> Why does this code segment not produce an error since it is using a for-each loop to modify elements?

By setting `i = 1` the loop is not modifying the underlying array, it is just modifying the dummy variable `i`, in that iteration of the loop.

> How does this code work even though the for each-loop is not being used properly.

By setting `arr[i] = 1` the loop is coincidentally just setting every element in the array to 1.  This works because the values of the array happen to also be the addressable indices in the array.